# How to set the directory properly in homestead-laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am a newbie in PHP and laravel. I have tried the whole night but problems keep occurring. After I set up the `homestead.yaml`, I ran `vagrant up` on the command line. The full content of file is as below(BTW, my OS is os x 10.10):

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/github_rsa

 folders:
- map: "/Users/yobichi"
  to: "/home/vagrant/yobichi"

sites:
- map: int2016.app
  to: "/home/vagrant/yobichi/public"

databases:
- homestead
```

everything seems going well, except an issue of database: `==> default: createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "homestead" already exists`. But when I enter the site address: `int2016.app` on the browser, an error of `403 forbidden` occurs. And I tried to enter the dir of "/home/vagrant/yobichi", it was empty. I wonder how should I set the directory of `folders` and `sites` properly so that I can solve the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have your Laravel project installation in your home folder? Because you link your complete home directory into the Vagrant box with this line `- map: "/Users/yobichi"`? You should install your project in a proper sub folder, i. e. `/Users/yobichi/laravel-project` and the link this folder into the box. The `folders` and `sites` have proper intendation in your `Homestead.yaml` file?

Comment: @codedge I don't know how to set them properly. My laravel project is under the folder of `/Users/yobichi/laravel` and its full dir is `/Users/yobichi/laravel/int2016 `. How should I set the `folder` and `site`. Thanks!

Comment: That is strange. With creating a new Vagrant box, the database is gone and newly created. So you should not get this error. Do you run the latest version of Homestead?

Comment: @codedge Yes. And indeed there are several `homestead.yaml` in my machine. Can I change the name of database as I like? For instance, can  I change it to `"db"`?

Comment: Yes, you can change it to a value you want, i. e. `db` oder `int2016`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following set up in your `Homestead.yaml`. Please also make sure that you have got proper intendation.

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: int2016
name: int2016
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "/Users/yobichi/laravel/int2016"
      to: "/home/vagrant/yobichi"

sites:
    - map: int2016.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/yobichi/public"

databases:
    - homestead
```

To create a complete new box you can run `vagrant destroy` and after that `vagrant up` again.

Comment: The error still exists. Do I have to run `vagrant up` again?

Comment: @user5779223 Yes, please destroy your box and create a new one. I updated my post with the necessary details

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! But do you know how to solve the problem of database? Anyway, I'll accept it.

Comment: @user5779223 That is strange. With creating a new Vagrant box, the database is gone and newly created. So you should not get this error. Do you run the latest version of Homestead?