# How to set the .env file to link laravel to Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am a newbie to both PHP and Laravel. Now I wish to connect my Laravel project to Mysql. But when I add the `auth` and try to register as an user, an error of `Access denied for user 'yobichi'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` occured. Here are the content of my `.env` file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:B21yfOUcsb5zmtlga5lori7olUMIGjeWhU2IrQ4grSc=
APP_URL=http://laravel.app

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravelDB
DB_USERNAME=yobichi
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I wonder whether I have any setting wrong in the `.env` file? Why can't I access the db properly? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You're using wrong db name or login or password. Did you add `yobichi` user? Check if you have created `laravelDB` db. Also, do you use DB in Homestead?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin he uses Homestead - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241540/how-to-set-the-directory-properly-in-homestead-laravel 

@user5779223 when using Homestead, please use `DB_USERNAME=homestead` and `DB_PASSWORD=secret` for the db created in your homestead box.

Comment: @codedge You are right!!! But now I have another error issue. When I `homestead ssh` and try to migrate `php artisan migrate`, it is said that `Could not open input file: artisan`, why?

Comment: When you `homestead ssh` into your box, please check which path you are in. You maybe need to do a `cd yobichi` to get into your the projects root directory. Then you can run `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: @codedge IT works not. Thanks for your help and patience all the time. And it is amazing you remember my question and my ID. HAHA :)

Comment: Happy to help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if user *yobichi* exists an has permission to read/write in *laravelDB* and also have to setup a password for your database user.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Laravel requires you to have a password on your DB account.

Also, have you actually created the user on your database?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Homestead, you should use these settings:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Also, you should connect to MySQL and create `db_name` database to use it.